# Parameter not being passed, but variable has the parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have another issue...here is the code

```
public int CheckForDuplicateRandomOrderNumber()
        {
            int randomNumber = GenerateRandomOrderNumber();
            string strCmdCheckForDuplicates = "sp_Check$For$Duplicate$Order$Numbers";
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(strCmdCheckForDuplicates, cn);
            SqlParameter myPm;
            myPm = cm.Parameters.Add("@OrderNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
            myPm.Value = randomNumber;
            myPm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            cn.Open();
            cm.ExecuteReader();
            cn.Close();

            if (randomNumber == 1)
            {
                return randomNumber;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
```

When I run this code I get an error saying the stored procedure is expecting a parameter to be passed and when I debug the variable has the parameter being passed. I have no idea why this is happening...
and another question that relates to this...
when I write this...

```
cm.parameters.add(new sqlparameter("@OrderNumber", sqldbtype.int)).value = randomNumber;
```

there is no parameter direction

Comment: By default a SqlParameter's direction is Input so specifying it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks, ok so that makes sense to why I never had a direction for input...Any idea about the rest of my issue?. My error comes when it tries to executereader, and my variable has the parameter to be passed.

Comment: Instead of `cm.Parameters.Add` try `cm.Parameters.AddWithValue`.

Comment: tried that as well, either way it goes I keep getting this error:
Procedure or function 'sp_Check$For$Duplicate$Order$Numbers' expects parameter '@OrderNumber', which was not supplied.

Comment: maybe it takes two parameters?

Comment: @Hogan got it figured out, in the comments below.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the issue was with my code...I forgot one line, one little line of code...

```
cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Its no wonder why it kept saying I wasn't supplying the parameter, it didn't know what I was doing...I guess this is a classic moment that goes to show how one missed line of code can cause hours of time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check that randomnumber is not null, if it is it will look like the parameter is missing.

Comment: I found out where I went wrong...So i'm going to answer my own question...This is pretty embarrassing..

Comment: @DarylBehrens - can't be that it is declared as `int` not `int?`

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours after posting before I can answer my own question...heres what the issue was..

Comment: I found out what the issue was with my code...I forgot one line, one little line of code...

    cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Its no wonder why it kept saying I wasn't supplying the parameter, it didn't know what I was doing...I guess this is a classic moment that goes to show how one missed line of code can cause hours of time trying to figure it out.

Comment: Glad you found your answer, you will never make that mistake again.  Make sure to answer the question once you can, and mark it as the correct answer so someone in the future can learn from your mistake.